# I can't disable scroll-x on my webpage, I've already tried everything

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll, responsive-design

```css
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 720px;
    margin: auto;
}

article {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

button {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: brown;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

p {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

code {
    font-family: monospace;
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

code.block {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

p .ejemplo {
    text-align: center;
}

.responsive-table {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

table td, th {
    padding: 8px;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Apuntes de JavaScript</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <!------------CAPITULO 1------------>
        <article>
            <h2>#1- Introducción</h2>
            <h3>Manipular elementos HTML</h3>
            <p>Con JavaScript puedes cambiar y manipular <b>contenido</b> HTML.</p>
            <p>Hay un método denominado <code>.getElementById()</code> que se usa para 
                seleccionar un elemento dentro del HTML.</p>
            <p class="ejemplo" id="ej1">Al tocar el botón cambiará este texto.</p>
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ej1').innerHTML='Este es el texto nuevo.'">
                Click aquí!</button>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I already tried `overflow: hidden` and all its variants. I have tried max-width, I deleted paddings
I even deleted the entire document line by line leaving it completely empty, but still in my browser the scroll remains when I put it in mobile size.
I use Google Chrome.
Anyone know what could be happening to me?

I dont know what's wrong with this

Comment: Please include the code.

Answer (score 0):

The question lacks some clarity, but I am speculating that maybe the issue is not that your content is overflowing. Perhaps the issue is just that you want to hide the scrollbars? If so, this css might be the solution you're looking for:

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar